# compilation error: tikz library 'positioning -plus' not found

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

I am trying to do something similar

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/flowchart/

and am using overleaf.com for it. However when I open this code in overleaf, I get an error at compilation step

"Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'positioning
-plus'. I looked for files named tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex and pgfli
brarypositioning-plus.code.tex, but neither could be found in the current texmf
 trees.."

I am getting similar error for "node-families" as well.

I understand that an obvious solution would be to install something like texmaker on my machine and download this. However I want to continue with the online editor. So can someone suggest a way around this issue

Comment: It's a user-contributed library from https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf. Upload into your project folder.

Comment: @ percusse...thank you so much for your comment.  It's fixed now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user missed the installation of some required libraries.